# mysql query or php

Tags: php, mysql

???????????

```html
  <div class="aa-search-box">
              <form action="" method="get">
                <input type="text" name="cat" placeholder="Pesquisar aqui. Ex.: 'CA 5111">
                <button type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
              </form>
            </div>
```

---pho

else {
        $aKeyword = explode(" ", $_GET['cat']);
        $get_products = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_title like % . $aKeyword[0] . %";
        if(count($aKeyword) > 1) {
                for($i = 1; $i < count($aKeyword); $i++) {
                         $get_products .= "OR product_title like % . $aKeyword[$i] . %";
                         }
                         }

```
}
```